# Export StarUML Project to Modelio

Tags: export, uml, project, staruml, modelio

Can anyone tell me how to export a StarUML project to Modelio environnement, Modelio seems to be better than StarUML, but I have a big work to do if the export is impossible. help please !!!

Comment: StartUML seems to have XMI import: https://github.com/staruml/XMI and Modelio (according to Google) has a XMI import.

Comment: Yes you're right, but in fact for a reason Modelio's doesn't accept StarUML's XMI

Comment: Yeah. How nice those OMG guys designed XMI in a way that anyone can implement his own "standard" :-( You should mention the above in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and you're right too, "standardisation, open-source, unification" are everyone mission These days. have you an answer for my question ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You might experiment with moving tiny models via XMI and see when it gets stuck - and then find work arounds until it swallows your model. Maybe there's a Modelio community that might help?